# Forging a double edged sword that slay witches

Tags: magic

Set in the 17th century CE, Scotland. After the Witchcraft Acts were passed by King James I, the authority trained a group of elite soldiers specifically targeting people believed to have committed the felony. These soldiers called themselves the "Royal Witchfinder Thirteen" whom were all highly skilled in witchcraft but spared from being executed, they pledged loyalty to the government and each received a unique gold ring that also served as a warrant. There are always 13 members and they are ranked according to their ability(bounty/threat level) and talent(kills) Their objective is to terminate all witches with extreme prejudice, even among themselves. (Magic is similar to D&D unless otherwise stated)

It is believed that a highly talented witch can fell hundred veteran soldiers easily.

A rough estimate that fewer than 0.001% (10 ppm) of Scotland's population knows at least basic trick of witchcraft.

Each member of Royal Witchfinder Thirteen must present their respective gold ring upon request, all soldiers below the rank of sergeant must obey the bearer of the ring without hesitations unless such order conflicts with the military and penal codes. **New**

Reward for returning a gold ring promise fame and luxury for the local and citizenship for outsider regardless of their talent in witchcraft.**New**

Any person should come to possession of a gold ring will automatically become a member of Royal Witchfinder Thirteen, there are always 13 gold rings.**New**

Retiring from Royal Witchfinder Thirteen is when one lose their own ring(think survival of the fittest) or is no longer alive(KIA, MIA or death by natural causes).**New**

No worry, all monetary rewards are eventually recycled or reissue to future member.**New**

**How can the authority prevent these Royal Witchfinder Thirteen from staging a coups d'état together?**

Comment: Real-world [Scotland's population in the 17th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography_of_Scotland#Population_totals_for_Scotland_1600.E2.80.932011) was somewhere between 500,000 (1600) and 800,000 (1700) people. Let's say it was 650,000, which should be fairly accurate for the mid-1600s. 0.0001% of that is 0.65 people. "Fewer than 0.0001%" then becomes zero. In other words, according to your numbers, **nobody knows even the basic tricks of witchcraft.** Hence, this isn't a problem. :-) If you want this to be even a potential problem, add two or three orders of magnitude. 1M is 1707.

Comment: @MichaelKjorling: that's not good I'll make amendment.

Comment: If one found a ring but is not a witch himself, what happen ?

Comment: @MakorDal: depends, sometimes fame can becomes a burden. remember every criminal wants to be clean.

Comment: @user6760 one of your new sections contradicts the original premise. _trained a group of elite soldiers_ and _Any person should come to possession of a gold ring will automatically become a member_

Comment: @user16295: that's the pioneer batch from the pilot project. Always 13 means the authority will start recruiting candidate when there's high turnover...

Comment: Wait, Why is your question asking about a sword? I didn't read anything about a sword.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon: it's just a figure of speech also for marketing purposes hee hee!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief you — as the author — are giving thirteen individuals complete and utter control of the modern equivalent of a company of main battle tanks each, in order that they might hunt down single individuals that may have anything from one battle tank, to a whole division. And you have seen to it that The Authorities do not have any tanks themselves... they only have infantry.

The Authorities have also instructed their infantry that "these individuals must be obeyed, unquestioningly".

Starting to see the deep pit that you have dug for The Authorities here?

This is why the real life concept of Checks & Balances exist. But what force do The Authorities have to counter that **massive** force that the troupe has, and thus create balance? These are their options...

- Threatening vital interests, such as their life, their loved ones? That is a really good way of getting them to rebel... no-one likes being threatened.
- Entice with rewards? The Authorities know that human greed is sooner or later likely to have at least a couple of them go "I want more...".
- Appeal to altruistic motives? What if one of them is a psychopath and do not care about altruism? What if one of them says "Hey, this witch is just like me..." and goes native? What if their altruism makes them think they can do a better job?

The only way that The Authorities can have this kind of force roaming the countryside and feel — reasonably — safe is if they have the means to revoke the powers of the baker's dozen, or in any other way nullify them.

Ways to do that...

- Two-man-rule (or in this case: thirteen-man-rule). These fellows cannot use their power alone... they must be in concert with each other... the thirteenth may be the equivalent of the "political officer".
- Batteries running flat. They do not have their powers for an infinite amount of time. At intervals they must check in and get an energy boost, and only The Authorities can give them that.
- Kill-switch. They have been implanted with a magic object or a spell that — upon the command of The Authorities — instantly kill, cripple or neutralize them. This kill-switch must not be removable.
- Fool proof brain-washing... indoctrinating them into undying, fanatic loyalty.

**EDIT:**

Here is one that can provide some really dramatic plot points...

**Boost their powers ten-fold**

The Authorities do not have magic themselves... but what they can do is to boost the offensive — and only the offensive — powers of these individuals. They can use them and do insane amounts of damage... but they **will** go out in a tremendous blaze if they try to use such powers on their own. It requires a significant amount of the others — with their nullifying and defensive powers — to balance out the offensive one and keep him cool, so that their powers do not run out of control.

Add the political officer... that can either choose to not help, leaving them one guy short, or add yet another boost so that it is impossible to keep the witch hunter in check.

Comment: "The Authorities" having a power to enhance power is quite ambiguous. Presumably, there is a method for enhancement that they don't share with the thirteen or some kind of items they use for the purpose. Both of these options have easily exploited flaws which someone with powers could bypass.

Comment: Yes it is ambiguous and loosely defined, and for a reason: to give the author options on how to implement this in their story / in their world. They key element here is that The Authorities *enable* or *enhance* the powers... but they will only only do it in such a way that it carries an inherent danger to the wielder to use them. So what if the wielder do not want this? Well... too bad: then you're a witch and you're getting put down.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to require the pledge of loyalty to government to take the form of **casting a spell on themselves** that prevents rebellion in some way.

*Clarification:* I didn't necessarily mean this has to be a "loyalty spell" that automatically makes them loyal.  That is a bit of a hand-wave and may not be possible within the rules you have in mind.  But they could be asked to cast some sort of spell that would hinder their rebellion.  Examples:

- **They must prevent themselves from entering the royal city** so they won't be able to directly challenge the king (but whoops! some other witches got in and now the thirteen can't defend the city.  Foolish plan by the king, but maybe a good plot point).
- **The king can hear all of their thoughts from a certain room in the castle.** They will not be able to mount a coup without the king being well prepared.
- **They cast a spell that strikes them with blindness if they kill any of the king's soldiers.**

There are a lot of possibilities here.

Another option is that **the thirteen witches do not know about each other.** Each thinks they are the only one with this role.  They are not likely to have the power to overcome the government alone.  They should be sworn to secrecy in order to prevent them discovering each other.  However, it is still possible that they will end up discovering each other (this possibility might make for some interesting plot tension).

Finally, there is the tried-and-true **hold someone hostage that they care about** option.  Boring, but it gives them a strong rationale both not to rebel and to cooperate in the first place.

Comment: TBH it's a bit of a self-sabotaging answer. You've put forth three alternatives, but then gone on to explain that number two wouldn't work and three would be boring. For more reasons on why option three doesn't work, please refer to my detailed answer. The only alternative left is the first one, basically a hand wavium magic spell, which IMO is taking an easy way out. As a result, with due respect, I don't think your answer actually provides viable solutions to the question.

Comment: @AmbarishSathianathan, I didn't say number two wouldn't work, only that it has the *possibility* of failure.  Holding hostages is not guaranteed to work, but it might work.  Your answer (which I like, by the way) also has the possibility of failure.  The thirteen may decide to mount a coup and try to extract the secret of the antidote, rather than cooperate.  While answers need a plausible chance of success, I don't see the possibility of failure as necessarily a bad thing...in the context of a story you almost certainly want there to be a chance the plan would fail.

Comment: @AmbarishSathianathan, as for the first point, I didn't necessarily mean a simplistic anti-rebellion spell.  See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Spy who watch the watchmen.**

Create a group of specialised spies who will observe the witch finder and see to it that they follow the rules. Make sure the witchfinder know about them. This way, you need fewer of them : how can they know for sure if they are watched or not ?

Create a few rules, simple, not too restrictive, but with only one penalty for violation : death of them and their beloved (I agree it's cliche, but it's efficient) Choose them for having beloved ! The ability and will to keep their kin alive is a good sign in their favour. The ruler will have to make everything he can to provide those people with golden cages, so that the price is not too steep ("serve or they die" makes the king a bad guy, while "serve and I'll provide for them, betray me and everything end" is... slightly better). Also, choose those that don't have a grudge against the king.

- thou shall not gather willingly with more than half your colleague (number arbitrary)
- thou shall not travel the land alone (you have to travel with a couple of guardsmen, either local or from king)
- thou shall protects your King's subject soul and life (bystander are to be protected to some extent, their soul is the most important, so killing those who side with a witch is appropriate)
- thou shall destroy the witches and all of their apparatus (no looting, be it an ear or a book of black magic)

In case of a breach of the rules, poison, blades, bolt, fire...
This can makes for quite a lot of drama as the rules are hard to breach unwillingly, but not impossible.
You can also create either insidious villain or brutal, obvious ones, who plays with the rules. Both from the witchfinder or from the watchers.

Answer (score 0):

### The gold ring both makes you a lord of the realm and the ultimate outlaw.

Luckily King James I of England was originally King James VI of Scotland so the usual Scottish rebellion is quiet quiet at this point in history.

The biggest problem I can see here starts like this:

- They're set against each other
- They're able to give orders to the king's own troops
- The greatest reward is for bringing in one of their own

This sounds like a recipe for civil war in the form of complete and utter chaos. Stopping them trying to overthrow the king is secondary to stopping them laying waste to half the country in pursuit of each other. Why bother hunting a hedge witch who turned [some guy into a newt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzYO0joolR0) when there are gold rings to recover?

Comment: Princes of the universe... There can be only one ?

Comment: @MakorDal - There _can_ be only one, but there _will_ always be 13. Wake up, time to die.

Answer (score -1):

One quick assumption before we proceed:

1. I'm assuming you're not looking for hand wavium answers, otherwise "binding magic spell!" would be a straightforward answer that you'd already have come up with. My answer presumes you can't simply use magic to make the Royal Witchfinder Thirteen do your bidding.

**The Problem with Moral Blackmail**

I see some suggestions of a moral blackmail, like holding someone hostage. There's thirteen people, each of whom have different thresholds and moral outlooks. Yes, two or three (or five) may agree because they truly love someone that you're holding hostage, but after a point you're just giving them reasons to turn against you the first chance they get. Most importantly, there will still be those who might not even care about losing loved ones at the price of power and freedom. I don't think this is practically a very feasible option.

**The Solution? Science b****!**

Imagine a lethal, long lasting disease that requires continuous medication. The royal apothecary (or equivalent medicinal personnel) could readily find a series of life threatening diseases that have no cure, only a treatment that keeps the infected alive, but does not cure them permanently. Given that we have real life examples of such diseases even with today's advanced technology, it does not seem implausible that 17th Century Scotland also has such diseases.

The only tricky part is keeping the cure a secret. Only the royal family and apothecary can know how to make the medication required to keep the disease at bay. It is critical that the Thirteen themselves can't get their hands on the cure without the authority's help.

**How you want it to go**

How I would do it is to infect the thirteen *before* the pardon and recruitment. You could do this by introducing the disease to their food, or the water supply. If they agree to be recruited, they're not killed. Instead, they're allowed to get sicker, demonstrating what the sickness can do to them. The forces that be then let the Thirteen know that powerful as they might be, there is no getting around real life issues like this without help.

Once the fear of death and their powerlessness is established, you give them the medication on a regular basis. And you treat them *well*, like they're heroes. Secret heroes maybe, but heroes. They're well fed, well taken care of, given enough time off and treated like valuable human beings all around. They're paid well too. Basically, you have to balance the carrot and the stick. The idea is to make it an *absolute* inconvenience for them to attempt a coup.

Now, if they rebel, their health deteriorates rapidly because you withhold any medication from them, eventually leading to their death. *And* they lose the good life that you've created for them. The point is not to actually kill them, it's to let them feel like it's not worth the effort to try anything stupid.

In my view, this should keep them in check, and add a layer of tension with this perpetual axe hanging over the heads of the Thirteen. In the end, when you want them to take each other out, just cut off the supply of medication.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed these 13 witches will try to murder each other as duty call, only crime is to collaborate and assist the enemy(which is fellow witches).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just realized that my answer would not change even if that assumption is removed. Have made the necessary edits accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure about disease as they are contagious, but there are poisons that can work that way or drugs that work the other way around.

Comment: See, not all diseases are contagious. There are lots of diseases and virus strains that are non-communicable but still deadly as hell. In Re: Poison, I did consider it. But a disease is sustainable, as long as its treated. Poisons are usually more harmful to the body in the short term. There's no antidote to postpone poisoning. As a result, their effects can't be sustainably postponed without fresh ingestion, which would lead to a logistical nightmare for the handlers of the Thirteen. A disease is easier to administer because it's a one time thing.

Comment: While holding hostages may not work, there is equally no guarantee that the witches will value their own lives enough to cooperate.  This scheme places them in a humiliated position, even if they are treated well, and they may prefer to stick it to the royal family and die in the process.  But they also might think that mounting a coup and hoping to obtain the secret of the antidote is their best option for survival.  It will not be lost on them that they are part of the same hated group of witches...what happens to them after they eliminate all the rest? The answer is good, but not ironclad.